# Why don't preferred stocks have the same holding period as common stocks to be considered as qualified dividends?

Tags: united-states, taxes, preferred-stocks, qualified-dividend, common-stocks

I read on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualified_dividend:

> - You must have held the stock for more than **60 days** during the 121-day period that begins 60 days before the [ex-dividend date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex-dividend_date). The ex-dividend date is the first date following the declaration of a dividend on which the buyer of a stock is not entitled to receive the next dividend payment. For calculation purposes, the number of days of ownership includes the day of disposition but not the day of acquisition.
> - In the case of preferred stock, you must have held the stock more than **90 days** during the 181-day period that begins 90 days before the ex-dividend date if the dividends are due to periods totaling more than 366 days

Why don't preferred stocks have the same holding period as common stocks to be considered as qualified dividends?

Comment: From IRS pub. 550: "Exception for preferred stock. In the case of preferred stock, you must have held the stock more than 90 days during the 181-day period that begins 90 days before the ex-dividend date if the dividends are due to periods totaling more than 366 days. If the preferred dividends are due to periods totaling less than 367 days, the holding period in the preceding paragraph applies." (60 days)